# How to use TMX map in android game

Tags: android, andengine

Last week i used andengine to use tmx map format to run as a game back ground.
but the and engine is pretty complex to understand.
i m wondering if could do it with out any engine.

So please spare some time for me and help me with this 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For game development, you'll be better off **with** a game engine, and AndEngine is very good. You'd better spare some time and learn how to use that engine, follow the tutorials - it will pay off during the development, because implementing **everything** on your own will cause some headaches.

Anyway, TMX is a simple to read XML format, so you could read up on the documentation, use XML parsing, base64 decoding and you'll have the data from TMX. Then you will need to implement your background drawing engine to draw it.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by Axarydax use Andengine .

here is example of TMX map in android

http://code.google.com/p/gcgame/

you can also see all andengine exapmles for tiles maps